# Android Studio won't stop asking for appcompat-v23

Tags: android, android-studio, android-appcompat

I do not want to use v23, I want to use v22.  I have v22 specified everywhere, but when I try to sync the gradle file, I get:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0
Install Repository and sync project
Open File
Show in Project Structure dialog
```

So I click Open File, and it opens the app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
signingConfigs {
    config {
        <snip>
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:22'
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.global.android.cwa'
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 20
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }
}
productFlavors {
    Pro {
        applicationId "com.global.android.pwa"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
    Simple {
        applicationId "com.global.android.swa"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
    Beta {
        applicationId "com.global.android.pwab"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
}
}
repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.0'
}
```

If I choose to Install Repository and sync project, then I get errors during compilation along the lines of:

```
 android-apt-compiler: [appcompat] D:\Android    SDK\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v23\styles_base.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

And I can see in external libraries that it is including appcompat-v23.

Can someone please help me exercise the demon out of gradle that keeps trying to include appcompat v23 in my project?

Comment: Why is the identity dependency not the same as the other versions?

Comment: Every dependency is out of date here.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the identity dependencies.  Despite all my googling and getting the app to build for a while now, I'm still a gradle newbies.

Comment: I know v22 is not the latest.  That is not the point.  I *should* be able to tell it to use whatever version I want, but it's not allowing that.

Comment: I'm guessing one of your dependencies is using v23, and you'll therefore need it.

Comment: But here's the thing...it was JUST WORKING FINE yesterday.  I was able to build and run the app just fine.  I then closed out Studio, came back the next day, and now it won't build because of this.  I always refuse the update offers android studio bombards me with (until I'm actually ready for the headache it will cause).  I didn't purposely change anything...and now it's broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
```

This version `has a dependency with support libraries v23.`
You **have to compile with API23**.

```
compileSdkVersion 23
```

Comment: Using appcompat v23 breaks other things at this point that I'd rather not deal with.  Can I just use an older version of the play-services?  I've tried using "play-services:8.7.03", but that doesn't seem to like that.

Comment: @Rob Yes you can use an older version, but the best choice is to use the latest versions of support libraries (v24) and to check why it breaks other things (what does it mean?)